# Using lists to access tensors like in MATLAB

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a tensor of a variable size as an input to a function in which I need to access specific elements.  Because the order of this tensor is variable, notation:

```
tensor[[i,j,k...]]
```

is not an option.  In MATLAB I would have a solution to the effect of:

```
access_array = [a,b,c,d,...];
tensor(access_array)
```

however this type of solution does not seem to work in Mathematica, and the documentation does not propose an equivalent.  Here is what I tried:

```
acc={a,b,c}
tensor[[acc]]
```

Thank you for your help,
Slava

Comment: Maybe `Extract[]` is more appropriate for you than `Part[]`?